# New to Ember - Binding elements/views to controllers

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ember.js

I come from an Angular background where you can link specific elements to controllers through markup attributes, and looking to do a similar thing w/ Ember.  However, I'm not sure if that's exactly how Ember works.

I'm only using Ember on a small portion of my application that has to render graphs.  I'd like specific elements to be attached to specific controllers that grab data from my Node backend.

Example code:

**HTML:**

```
#graph
  script(type="text/x-handlebars", data-template-name="index").
    {{pie-chart data=content}}
```

**app.js:**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  controllerName: 'application'
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  content: [
  {
    "label": "Equity",
    "value": 12935781.176999997,
    "type": "money"
  }
   ...
  ]
});
```

The problem with my above code is that Ember attaches the Ember Chart (pie-chart) to the bottom of the DOM (because I'm not really using any views/haven't specified a `rootElement`.  What's the best way to build out this application, knowing that I'm not particularly interested in scaling it further to act as a JS Framework.

Comment: Do you have an application template that includes an outlet somewhere?

Comment: I don't because I'm using Jade.  Is that something I should have on top of Jade?

Comment: I'm trying to work out how the pie-chart is even appearing in the dom without it.

Comment: I'm using Ember Charts, a lib developed by Addepar... maybe it's built in somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need an application template for this to work I believe:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2> Title </h2>

    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

The outlet is where ember renders all the views including your index one.

Can you try adding this to your application?

**Edited based on comment:**

```
{{pie-chart data=content}}
```

Where you say "data=content" what this is actually saying is:

"Get me the content of the IndexController and set the pie-charts data property to that content"

It looks like you have defined your content in the ApplicationController.  Try creating an IndexController and set the content like you have in that AppplicationController

I would also make it an ArrayController because I believe you are passing it an Array?

Comment: Sure- I understand how `{{outlet}}` works.  My question is more along the lines of how do I bind Controllers to specific elements... or is that just an Angular thing, and if so, what is the Ember alternative?

Comment: I still don't think you understand my question, although your answer was helpful to learning Ember as a whole.  My pie chart is *working fine*.  If you need me to clarify anything in my question, let me know, but I think I'm being pretty clear.  I'm trying to link Controllers to Views/specific elements.

Comment: Oh ok, so the pie-chart is working.  What is the problem then? It's very easy to link a view/controller  a view has a context equal to the controller so in your handlebars template you can reference any property on the controller like this  {{someProperty}}